# Admob with AndEngine Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: admob, andengine

I seem to be getting a run time error with one of my apps concerning Admob. The frustrating issue is that on two other of my apps Admob has been integrated in exactly the same way through XML and functions as expected.

The Ad itself seldom shows although sporadically it appears after a long time until it is refreshed then it vanishes once more.

If registered as a test device, the default test banner is displayed.

During app execution the following appears in the Logcat repeatedly seemingly at every refresh interval,

```
E/Ads(12081): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderAd is not defined (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:... inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=48:1)
E/Web Console(12081): Uncaught ReferenceError: renderAd is not defined at http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:...
E/Ads(12081): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:...
E/Web Console(12081): Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined at http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:...
```

But, on RecievedAd() is still called.

I am testing this on a Samsung Galaxy 3, 4.0.4. On on a SG 2, 2.1 update 1 it appears to be fine. Although as mentioned on the same SG3, the other two applications function correctly.

My exact Admob implementation can be seen with a different question I asked earlier in the year here: [Admob Unable to destroy activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654533/admob-unable-to-destroy-activity)

Has anyone had similar issues?